# C - how to use PROGMEM to store and read char array

Tags: c, arduino

I have three char arrays, and I don't want Arduino store those in [SRAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_random-access_memory), so I want to use PROGMEM to store and read in [flash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory), instead.

```
char *firstArr[]={"option 1","option 2","option 3","option 4"};
char *secondArr[]={"test 1","test 2"};
```

Answer (score 7):

There's an example on how to do precisely this [on the Arduino website](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PROGMEM). (See under "Arrays of strings".)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is an example on the Arduino web site. But I want to make you aware of a [compiler bug in GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=34734), and the following work-around:

```
/**
 * Alternative to PROGMEM storage class
 * 
 * Same effect as PROGMEM storage class, but avoiding erroneous warning by
 * GCC.
 * 
 * \see http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=34734
 */
#define PROGMEM_ __attribute__((section(".progmem.data")))
```