# An array of strings stored in flash with PROGMEM in Arduino

Tags: c, arduino

I am using AVR-GCC version 4.7.0, and when I attempt to create an array of strings in FLASH memory I get the error:

> variable ‘menu’ must be const in order to be put into read-only section by means of ‘**attribute**((progmem))’

I am using this code:

```
const char menu0[] PROGMEM = "choice0";
const char menu1[] PROGMEM = "choice1";
const char menu2[] PROGMEM = "choice2";
const char menu3[] PROGMEM = "choice3";
const char menu4[] PROGMEM = "choice4";
const char menu5[] PROGMEM = "choice5";

const char *menu[] PROGMEM = {menu0, menu1, menu2, menu3, menu4, menu5};
```

I have already read Stack Overflow question *[C - how to use PROGMEM to store and read char array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13093927/c-how-to-use-progmem-to-store-and-read-char-array)*, but all the answers I see don't include the `const` keyword which makes me believe that they were written before it was needed.

How does one fix this problem?

---

```
const char * const menu[] PROGMEM = {menu0, menu1, menu2, menu3, menu4, menu5};
```

was the answer.

Comment: Try this: `const char * const menu[]...`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try

```
const char* const menu[] PROGMEM...
```

Thus the array itself is constant, not a mutable array of `const char*` pointers, as it were in the original code.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I actually just tried that, and was about to post the fact. Appreciations all around.